# OutOfBoundsException in my custom factory class

Tags: php, symfony

I try to create an custom authentication provider in Symfony 2, just for fun. I follow this doc http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html.

Here what i do :

## security.yml

```
providers:
facebook_provider:
        id: facebook.security.provider 
firewalls:
admin_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        facebook:
            check_path: /login_check
            default_target_path: /
            provider: facebook_provider
```

I create a bundle with the namespace Kmelkez\AuthBundle

In the namespace Kmelkez\AuthBundle\Security, I create my custom files FacebookFactory, FacebookListener, FacebookProvider, FacebookToken.

I load them in my services.yml file

## services.yml

```
 services:
     facebook.security.provider:
     class:  Kmelkez\AuthBundle\Security\FacebookProvider

 abstract_listener:
     abstract: true
     class: Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\AbstractAuthenticationListener

 facebook.security.listener:
     class:  Kmelkez\AuthBundle\Security\FacebookListener
     parent: abstract_listener
```

Finally, in my factory custom class, for now I keep it simple and I call the listener & provider like that :

## Factory class

```
  class FacebookFactory extends AbstractFactory
  {
   protected function createAuthProvider(ContainerBuilder $container, $id, $config,  $userProviderId)
    {
      $providerID = 'facebook.security.provider' . $id;      
      return $providerID;
    }

   protected function getListenerId()
   {
    return 'facebook.security.listener';
   }

   public function getPosition()
   {
    return 'pre_auth';
   }

   public function getKey()
   {
    return 'facebook';
   }
  }
```

When I go to the /login_check route, I have an exception :

```
OutOfBoundsException: The index "4" is not in the range [0, -1].
```

And the useful stacktrace :

in Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition.php
line 255
at Definition->replaceArgument('4', 'admin_area') in Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\ResolveDefinitionTemplatesPass.php
line 127
at ResolveDefinitionTemplatesPass>resolveDefinition('facebook.security.listener.admin_area', object(DefinitionDecorator)) in Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\ResolveDefinitionTemplatesPass.php line 50

any ideas ?

Thx

Answer (score 4):

Finally, I find the problem :

My listener extends an abstract class : AbstractAuthenticationListener

So, I edit services.yml to have something like that :

```
facebook.security.listener:
class:  Kmelkez\AuthBundle\Security\FacebookListener
parent: security.authentication.listener.abstract #this key is defined in security_listeners.xml
abstract: true
```

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing the answer. I had the EXACT same problem, and this out of bounds exception with no useful information was driving me nuts. I couldn't figure out what I was doing wrong or what caused the problem. Finding your answer was super lucky as it made everything work right away...